# How can I calculate the insert bulk size

Tags: java, mongodb

I have a collection with documents like this

```
{userId: "123", profile: [{"prof1":"p"}, {"prof2" : "4"}], loc: "loc"}
```

I want to know what is the best bulk size number to insert the documents 100,500,1000?
And how can I calculate this?

Thanks

Comment: Can you please be more specific

Comment: It depends. I would test the different sizes to see which performs best on your equipment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best total bulk insert size can vary quite a bit. Probably 50KB - 500KB. The best way to find out is to benchmark at several bulk insert sizes and see which is fastest on your driver, version of MongoDB, etc.

Comment: Which values should I treat to see the performance of such benchmark (%lock, %faults,...) ? In addition I have also a runtime component that is querying a lot, and I don't want to harm it's performance

Comment: I'd just recommend benchmarking at the application level, not at the database level. Make sure you're using your driver's 'safe' mode so that you're guaranteed a round trip.